# strlen() issue in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation, error-log, filtered-nav

I am getting the following error message when multiple attributes are selected in a category listing and pagination is clicked.

```
ERR (3): Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given  in /home/site/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php on line 94
```

The error relates to this block of code:

```
    public function apply(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request, $filterBlock)
{
    $filter = $request->getParam($this->_requestVar);
    if (is_array($filter)) {
        return $this;
    }
    $text = $this->_getOptionText($filter);
    if ($filter && strlen($text)) {
        $this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $filter);
        $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($this->_createItem($text, $filter));
        $this->_items = array();
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I understand strlen only counts a string but can anyone tell me

1. Why it could be getting an array
2. Is this a bug in Magento (1.9.3.7)
3. How to fix?

Comment: I doubt this is a bug in 1.9.3.7 ... Have you any custom attribute with cutom source models?

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've yet to solve this issue.

Comment: If you have time for, please add some output from your logs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so it's `array` because when you look at the line

```
$text = $this->_getOptionText($filter);
```

It calls the

```
    /**
     * Get option text from frontend model by option id
     *
     * @param   int $optionId
     * @return  string|bool
     */
    protected function _getOptionText($optionId)
    {
        return $this->getAttributeModel()->getFrontend()->getOption($optionId);
    }
```

and return type of this method is either `string` or `bool`. So please log the `$text` value and check what you get.

Comment: I did log $text and it did show an array. Why it's giving me an array I have no idea. I'm not too concerned it's giving an array as it doesnt seem to impact the working of the website but i'd like to extend/fix that function so it works with an array or string and stops the warning in system.log

Answer (score 1):

**Not really an answer**,  just to long for a comment (will be deleted)

As @Keyur Shah said `_getOptionText($optionId)` **should** return a string or false, but it seems to be possible to get an array ...

- `_getOptionText` calls `getOption($optionId)`
- `getOption($optionId)` calls `$source->getOptionText($optionId)`

  ```
  # Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract

  /**
   * Get a text for option value
   *
   * @param  string|int $value
   * @return string|bool
   */
  public function getOptionText($value)
  {
      $options = $this->getAllOptions();
      // Fixed for tax_class_id and custom_design
      if (sizeof($options) > 0) foreach($options as $option) {
          if (isset($option['value']) && $option['value'] == $value) {
              return isset($option['label']) ? $option['label'] : $option['value'];
          }
      } // End
      if (isset($options[$value])) {
          return $options[$value];
      }
      return false;
  }
  ```

If using custom source model you can add logging to:

```
$options = $this->getAllOptions();
```

and/or

```
if (isset($options[$value])) {
    return $options[$value];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supress the warning and check contents of the unwanted array by using `Mage::log()` like this:

```
$text = $this->_getOptionText($filter);
if (is_array($text)) {
    Mage::log($text);
    if ($filter && $text) {
        $this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $filter);
        $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($this->_createItem($text, $filter));
        $this->_items = array();
    }
} else {
    if ($filter && strlen($text)) {
        $this->_getResource()->applyFilterToCollection($this, $filter);
        $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($this->_createItem($text, $filter));
        $this->_items = array();
    }
}
```

It might help you track down the source of the problem.

Most probably a custom module which modifies swatches or product attributes in a certain way is causing this issue.

Comment: First parameter for `_createItem($text, $filter)` has to be a string, not an array.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that he's getting an array. This would just remove the warning from system.log (which is what he wants based on his comment on the other answer)

Comment: I guess he wants a working solution  at the end - not just supress the warning. Have you tested this? He should track down, WHY he is getting an array. **Edit:** pasing an array reults in _Warning: strip_tags() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given  in app\code\core\Mage\Core\Helper\Abstract.php_

Comment: You are right, the proper way would be to track down the real issue.

Comment: Yes, I'd like a working solution which won't impact the website. I could make the error go away but I'd like a proper fix. I'll check all active extensions to ensure none of those are the culprit and report back.

Comment: @PaulDonnelly try checking the contents of the array, might be something useful that could help you track down the problem. Updated the answer.